# How to serialize data related to the current item of a jQueryUI sortable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, list

I am using jQueryUI 1.8.14. I would like to implement a [sortable list](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable) and to save related item position changes in my application database each time an user changes an item position.

*To do that I am planning to retrieve and serialize the `id` value and the new position value of the item that has just changed its position* (I need to make that so to generate and prepare data in order to perform an AJAX HTTP request). Anyway, using the `serialize` method as descibed in the [official documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable) it will serialize all item `id` values in a submittable string (eg: `key=1&key=2&...`), but I would like to serialize **only** the current item `id` value and retrieve its new position value.

**How can I make\code that?**

---

At this time I am trying to implement that functionality this way:

JavaScript code:

```
$jQ(function() {
  $jQ("#sortable_list").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(event, ui) {

      // Here I would like to "serialize" ONLY the current updated item and
      // then perform the AJAX HTTP request

      // alert($jQ("#sortable_list").sortable("serialize"))
      ...
    }
  });
  $jQ( "#sortable_list" ).disableSelection();
});
```

HTML code

```
<ul id="sortable_list">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="key_1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="key_2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

*For istance*, if I change the item position related to the `id="key_2"` I would like to serialize just that data to `key=2` (note: generally the `serialize` method generates data like `key=1&key=2&...`). Furthermore, I would like to include the current\new position of that item (eg: `new_position=1`). Finally, I would like to perform the AJAX HTTP request including those parameters: `<URL_string>?key=2&new_position=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested it http://jsfiddle.net/kRsCE/

```
$jQ(function() {
  $jQ("#sortable_list").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var itemid = $(ui.item).attr('id');
        var position;
        $jQ("sortable_list > li").each(function(index) {
            if($(this).attr('id') == itemid) {
               position = index;
               return;
            }
        });
        $.post('yourajaxscript', '&key='+itemid+'&new_position='+position, function(data) {
            //handle response
        });
    }
  });
  $jQ( "#sortable_list" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: I can not retrieve the `position` value outside the `$jQ("sortable_list > li").each(function(index) { ... }` JavaScript statement. I get the following error: `position is not defined * $jQ(function () {$jQ("#sortable_li...ortable_list").disableSelection();});`.

Comment: More, maybe I can use the `ui.position` (as described in the Official Documentation) instead of running the `$jQ("sortable_list > li").each(function(index) { ... }` code... but how to use that? If I run the `alert(ui.position)` I get an alert message like the following: "`[object Object]`"... how can I inspect that object?

Comment: It seems more reliable to retrieve the dragged item from the ui object. Thanks for pointing me to it. I updated the code. I agree its not very nice to itterate over the list but I don't think there's another solution. The ui.position though gives you the exact position of the element related to the document (in pixels). So, yes, you could use it to determine the position (`ui.position.top`), but then you've to compare it to the position of the other elements. Not much better solution.

Comment: So it is not possible to retrieve the position of the just dragged element... thanks anyway.